# OxyPlot does not update view when adding Points (Dispatcher)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, oxyplot

I'm working on a performance monitor showing plotting some x/y Points as AreaSeries. For presentation I'm updating my view several seconds and adding measuring points. Because of `InvalidOperationException`, I need to add the points inbetween a Dispatcher. I want to see the added points real-time - but the view does not update. There is no issue with the points or anything other, because adding all points before, I get my Plot.

.xaml file

```
<UserControl x:Class="Gauge_3.PerformanceMonitor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Gauge_3"
             xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <oxy:PlotView x:Name="fMonitor" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <oxy:PlotView x:Name="sMonitor" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <oxy:PlotView x:Name="nMonitor" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

.cs snippet, calling from another class

```
public void PlotRealTime(double percent)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                DataPoint dPoint = new DataPoint(new DateTime(2017, 01, 01, 14, internalCounter, 00).ToOADate(), percent);
                sArea.Points.Add(dPoint);
                if (internalCounter == 0)
                    sMonitor.Model.Series.Add(sArea);

                sMonitor.Model.InvalidatePlot(true);
            }));

            internalCounter++;
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps provide more context as to what `sArea` is and how it's initialized.